# Cookie possibly not set or overflowed because it was too large

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Using a tutorial on how to implement rails authentication with devise and angular as front end.

http://www.sotoseattle.com/blog/2014/10/30/Devise-Angular-Rails/

All good except the `cookie` error I get when I try log in, or when I signup, cause after a valid signup user is signed in automatically.

Error I get is:

```
Cookie 'logged_user' possibly not set or overflowed because it was too large (8279 > 4096 bytes)!
```

the signIn function in angular:

```
$scope.signIn = function(new_user){
  data = { user: new_user };
  $http.post('/users/sign_in', data)
  .success(function(data){
    $scope.user = {};
    $cookieStore.put('logged_user', data);
    $scope.setForm('');
    $location.path('/dashboard');
  })
  .error(function(data,status){
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
  });
};
```

Is it ok to use cookies at all? I assume the problem comes from this line:

```
$cookieStore.put('logged_user', data);
```

but being not very experienced in js or angular, I am not sure how to go about it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to logged out or not if not then devise provide the method for logged out . May be this help you.

Comment: @VinayGupta to be able to log out, I need first to log in, and I can't log in. Devise provide the method for logged out but this will not work out of the box when using it with angular.

Comment: Do you need the user data in a cookie? otherwise you could just store the user data in local storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using cookies for managing sessions is fine, but 8k is a pretty big cookie.  As you've seen, the size is limited to 4k.

Remember that your cookie will be sent to the server in every single request from the browser.  The reason for the (large, IMHO) 4k limit is that you want your requests to be light.  Any time you add anything to the session hash using the cookie store you are adding it to the cookie.  Are you sure that you need everything that you've put in there?

For documentation that mentions this limit and describes the session store, check http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html

Comment: "Are you sure that you need everything that you've put in there?" - :) good question, no, I am not sure.. I expect in this cookie to have only a kind of secret_key that will be used to identify user.. Also, I am not sure I understand what else is being saved in cookie that makes it so large and how to get rid of unnecessary things.

Comment: The cookiestore is, by default, only signed.  You can optionally encrypt or encrypt and sign it.  You could try decoding it and seeing what's inside.  If memory serves, it's base 64 encoded.  That reference page should tell you.  Typically, I use an ID value in the session cookie to reference a database table.  Whatever I need to track about someone I can retrieve from that table using the ID from the cookie.

Comment: I deleted the cookie used by this app from chrome console, refreshed the page to generate the new one, size was 301, then I type in the email and pass to authenticate, and I see in browser's js console an html version of `sign_in` action, and I looked into the network tab, and I see that the request was `POST text/html`, therefore the response is also a html and not json. Angular saves the response (html code) into `data` and put it in `cookies`..  this is the way I see it, am I right? https://gist.github.com/rmagnum2002/da46fe4901488685e8d9

Comment: You may want to switch to Canary and, from there, take a look at what's actually in the cookie being sent back and forth..